# Permissions required to use cp in linux?

Tags: linux, bash, permissions

I am working on a school assignment and I am trying to understand permissions required to copy (cp) the file date (from /bin) to my home directory.

The question asks that if permissions for date were set to rwxrwxrw-, whether that would be possible. Since I am a member of the Others group, my permissions would be wr-, so this should be possible.

I then tried to do that on the school server, the permissions that date has is rwxr-xr-x. It succeeded. Considering that as a member of the Others group, my permissions are r-x, shouldn't I NOT be able to copy this file, since I am writing it to my home directory?

Or does cp only invoke read permissions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

cp invokes read permission on the file you are trying to copy. You should also have write permissions in the target folder